# VertX mongo auth client returns : No account found for user [username]

Tags: mongodb, vert.x

I am using mongodb Community edition. I have created a user in the mongodb. The user exists and the Vertx mongodb client successfully starts when config is initialized with this user.

> *var mongoconfig = {
>       "connection_string": "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017",
>       "db_name": "admin",
>       "username": "username",
>       "password": "password",
>       "authSource": "admin" };*

The db.auth command returns 1 for the same user from mongo shell.

> db.getName() 
>   admin
>
> db.auth("username","password"); 
>   1

Now, when I try to authenticate with the same user using mongo AuthProvider implementation, there is an error returned:

> **io.vertx.ext.auth.mongo.AuthenticationException: No account found for user [username]**

My code is exactly as per the Vertx mongo authprovider implementation example.

```
var mongoClient = MongoClient.createShared(vertx, mongoconfig);  
var authProperties = {};  
var authProvider = MongoAuth.create(mongoClient, authProperties);  
var authInfo = {   "username" : "username", "password" : "password" };
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Vert.x Auth Mongo does not use database accounts to authenticate users.

Instead, it uses a specific collection in your database (by default, the `user` collection).

Check out the docs section about [Auth Mongo implementation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-auth-mongo/java/#_mongo_auth_provider_implementation).

Comment: Thanks @tsegimont. This is what I figured out after your comment. If i Dont mention the CollectionName, the Auth client cannot figure this out and so gives an error - No account found. If I set the Collection Name to "system.users" and the username/password fields - then the auth provider cannot figure out the password and returns "Invalid Username/password". What is the right way to pass the username/password? Is there a full example? The vertx mongo auth example is highly simplistic.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue... When I point to the correct collection I get the included username and password error. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Have you managed to find the answer? I'm stuck in this too now